# Lim sup and Lim inf of real-valued functions

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

In General Topology Chapters 1 - 4 by Bourbaki on [p. 359](https://books.google.com/books?id=kTFSfmsjDM0C&pg=PA359) I have found the property

> $\limsup_{x \to a} fg = \limsup_{x \to a}f \lim_{x \to a}g$

whenever both sides are defined and $f,g \geqslant 0$. However, I think this is still true, if only $g \geqslant 0$. Any hints for a proof?

Comment: You can probably find several posts with analogous result for sequences. For example, 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510314/proof-that-limsup-a-nb-n-limsup-a-n-lim-b-n
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776517/product-of-limitsuperior-of-bounded-sequences
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244661/if-lim-n-to-inftya-n-a-in-mathbbr-prove-that-limsup-n-to-infty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just formulated my solution to this problem.

[image]