# Is liminf of a product equal to the product of liminfs?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My question is just for curiosity. I was thinking if  is true this curious affirmation:

Let $a_n$ a  bounded sequence of nonnegative numbers and $b_n$ a convergent sequence of negative numbers. Then $\lim \inf (a_n b_n) = (\lim \inf a_n)   (\lim \inf b_n) $
This is true?

Comment: For $b_n\ge 0$ see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275124/checking-of-a-solution-to-how-to-show-that-lim-sup-a-nb-n-ab and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510314/proof-that-limsup-a-nb-n-limsup-a-n-lim-b-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_n=-1$ for all $n$.  Say $a_n$ alternates between 1 and 3.  Then $(\lim\inf b_n)(\lim\inf a_n)=-1$, but $\lim\inf a_n b_n=-3$.

Comment: What do you think if $a_n$ is convergent?

Comment: @mathstudent If both sequences are convergent, their termwise product is also convergent.

Comment: You don't even need to go to negative numbers to get this result...

Comment: oh you're right guys, sorry. I was sleepy when I writed the question. Thanks for your attentions!